# Notes error: You are not allowed to update the certifier log while creating a new user

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I am trying to create a new user in IBM Domino v9.0. via java api and I am using Notes.jar.
The IBM Domino installation I have made on amazon ec2-instance, and i am trying to run a java code to create new user locally in IBM Domino. While creating user I am getting the following error.
Caused by: NotesException: Notes error: You are not allowed to update the certifier log (Reddy).
The user with which i am creating session has "Manager" Access on "certlog.nsf" database. The code that i am using is as follows

```
private static void recreateCreateUserError(String host, String userName, String password) throws Exception{
    Session session = NotesFactory.createSession(host, userName, password);
    Registration reg = session.createRegistration();
    reg.setRegistrationServer(session.getServerName());
    reg.setCreateMailDb(true);
    reg.setCertifierIDFile("C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\Domino\\data\\cert.id");
    reg.setIDType(Registration.ID_HIERARCHICAL);
    reg.setMinPasswordLength(5);
    reg.setRegistrationLog("log.nsf");
    reg.setMailInternetAddress("rajesh.parupalli@concentrix.com");
    reg.setUpdateAddressBook(true);
    reg.setStoreIDInAddressBook(true);
    reg.setEnforceUniqueShortName(true);
    if (!reg.registerNewUser("Reddy", // last name
            "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\Domino\\data\\sreddy2.id", // file to be created
            "CN=WIN-3G1ICLOT664/O=Concentrix", // mail server
            "Santhosh", // first name
            "", // middle initial
            "xxxxxx", // certifier password
            "Delhi", // location field
            "Comment", // comment field
            "mail\\sreddy2.nsf", // mail file
            "", // forwarding domain
            "xxxxx")) // user password
        throw new RuntimeException("failed to register new user");
}
```

Please let me know what i am missing out.

Thanks
Vishvadeepak Tewari

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the user with which you create session has every privilege in domino server document's security tab, e.g. Access server, Sign or run unrestricted methods and operations.